# Sum unique names of column with thouthands of rows

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm trying all the unique different names and amounts on a sheet, I'm trying to create a macro that collects all the names and sums the payments next to it. Names are in column A and payiments on column B and I need the sum in columns C-Name and D-Total.

How is this done in VBA.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try a Pivot Table?

Comment: _"I'm trying to create a macro..."_  Actually, you're trying to get someone else to create it for you. You have failed to post your attempt so I can't see how that statement is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below :

```
Sub sumTotal()

    'dim array to store unique names
    Dim uniqueArray As Variant

    'Sheets(your chosen sheet)
    With Sheets(1)

        'find last cell with value in A
        Set last = .Range("A:A").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

        'for each cell in column to last value found
        For n = 1 To last.Row
            'if name isnt in array yet
            If Not InArray(.Cells(n, 1).Value, uniqueArray) Then

                'check if array is empty redim/resize array and attribute value
                If IsEmpty(uniqueArray) Then
                    ReDim uniqueArray(0)
                    uniqueArray(0) = .Cells(n, 1).Value
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve uniqueArray(0 To UBound(uniqueArray) + 1)
                    uniqueArray(UBound(uniqueArray)) = .Cells(n, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next

        'for each of the gathered names
        For n = 0 To UBound(uniqueArray)
            'set name in column C
            .Cells(n + 1, 3).Value = uniqueArray(n)
            'set value of application sum if column D
            .Cells(n + 1, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A:A"), uniqueArray(n), Range("B:B"))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
Function InArray(val As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

    'set default value of InArray
    InArray = False
    If IsEmpty(arr) Then Exit Function

    'for each name in array
    For n = 0 To UBound(arr)
        'if name is found
        If val = arr(n) Then
            'return true
            InArray = True
            'ext function earlier
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Lovely code dump. Thanks for encouraging people to ask vague, off-topic questions and providing copy-pasta material for noobs to ask about when it blows up due to all the implicit `ActiveSheet` references in there. `</sarcasm>` - please avoid answering blatantly off-topic questions, and when you do answer, please provide *at least* some minimal explanation of what's going on and why, *especially* when OP is clueless. Code dumps like this aren't helping anyone, it's like doing someone else's CS assignment. FWIW that code is terribly inefficient and makes bug-prone assumptions.

Comment: @Mat's Mug - Yep, you're right, just I kinda spend some hours today trying to help out people on other questions with little to no avail and near no answer (people seem to ask and disappear), and ended up doing exactly what you said, a `code dump` for a poorly made question. Should I try editing the question or I'm i better off deleting it?

Comment: You have several options, and the decision is entirely in your hands - but I doubt the question is salvageable by anyone but the OP. That said I agree, today's crop is especially disappointing so far :)

Comment: Meant the answer -.-

Comment: eh, I'd just remove it and get my -2 rep back =) ...or wait to see if it gets to -3, then get a badge for deleting it!

Comment: I can't, OP accepted it. Can't delete it now.

Comment: ♪ let it go ♪ ;-)